# Converting an NSString with ASCII characters > 127

Tags: objective-c, hex, extended-ascii

I am at a road block, though I have used Stack Overflow to get me about 90% of the way.

My ultimate goal is to pass an `NSString` (e.g. @"51 EC") which is two space-separated hex codes.

I use the following routine to convert this to an `ASCII` based `NSString`.

```
- (NSString *)hexToString:(NSString *)string {
    // this routine takes a 2 byte HEX coded sting
    // with a space between them and converts to
    // another string that is ASCII character based

    NSMutableString *newString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:string];
    unsigned value;
    while ([scanner scanHexInt:&value]) {
        [newString appendFormat:@"%c",(char)(value & 0xFF)];
    }
    string = [newString copy];
    return string;
}
```

which seems to be working.

I send this `NSString` to a device with a serial cable. The device on the other end echoes the `ASCII` code string back (which can include characters with `ASCII` values > 127 dec).

I found the following routine:

```
- (NSString *)stringToHex:(NSString *)str { 
    NSUInteger len = [str length];
    unichar *chars = malloc(len * sizeof(unichar));
    [str getCharacters:chars];        

    NSMutableString *hexString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        [hexString appendFormat:@"%02x", chars[i]];
    }
    free(chars);
    return hexString;
}
```

I want to read this `NSString` and convert it to `@"51EC"`

What I get back when passing the `ASCII` coded `NSString` is `@"51cf"`

It seems like all bytes < 127 convert properly. I think it is because the routine uses unichar
and that might limit it to 0 to 127.

Hopefully I gave enough info to ask the right question.

Maybe there is a more elegant solution.

You can assume I am an experienced hardware engineer, but a novice at Objective-C.

Comment: `What I get back when passing the ASCII coded NSString is @"51cf"`: After you called `stringToHex:` or before?

Comment: Why don't you convert the `NSString` to an `int` before sending it and convert it back to an `NSString` after receiving it? You would have much less data to send over the cable.

Comment: the 51cf is after the stringToHex call... the cf should be EC if but I don't know how to extract it from the NSString properly. the receiving end wants to see an ascii coded string (that part is working)         I have no control over what is sent back. it is HEX coded data and the 3rd party library reads it into a string then I have to extract / interpret the data

Comment: the receiving end wants to see an ascii coded string (that part is working)  I have no control over what is sent back.